# What is the difference between the two identically named "Pull Requests" buttons in "Team Explorer - Home" pane in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, github, visual-studio-extensions

I've recently started learning about [GitHub Extension for Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.github.com/) by installing it locally in my Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition and connecting it to my GitHub account. I'm also quite new to git and know little more than basics about versioning systems.

Now, on some projects that are clones of forks of public repositories, in the "Projects" section of "Home" page of the "Team Explorer" pane, I get (among others) [two buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EIYsQ.png) that are both titled the same - "**Pull Requests**" and both have the same tooltip: "Pull Requests". I fail to understand the difference between them by looking at their icons.

Found nothing on this by searching stackoverflow and looking through the web/tutorials.

When I click on the right-side button it opens a "GitHub" pane containing some open pull requests that I also can find on the GitHub website in the project that I made a fork from, in the "Pull requests" tab.
Clicking on the left-side button just gives me this [information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJ0Ki.png). Doing what it says (connecting) doesn't appear to change anything. I don't know specifically what this button is for and I would like to know.

Can someone explain clearly what each of them is referring to? So much better if I can also arrive at understanding the git/GitHub aspects involved behind each.

Comment: Maybe one of them views pull requests and one of them creates pull requests?

Comment: @matt Haha, seems it's just that, thanks. My question looks now like it's better off as only a personal suggestion to the extension team to differentiate a little more the two buttons.

Comment: Should I delete this question? Seems to me that it doesn't contribute value, more so with fact that the "understanding git/GitHub aspects involved" is rendered obsolete after @matt 's response.

Comment: Yes, that would be the Right Thing To Do, I think.

Comment: @liviriniu you might want to submit that a a suggestion to the VS team instead : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/suggest-a-feature?view=vs-2019

Comment: @tsimbalar They have an official link to their repository's issue tab on GitHub: https://github.com/github/VisualStudio/issues I'm gonna place the suggestion there.

Comment: @liviriniu, I suggest you could [mark your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) so that it will help other community members search and handle similar issues. Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging around on the web, among other helpful materials I came upon [this VS developer community thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/344645/pull-requests-in-visual-studio-you-are-not-connect.html) that helped me arrive at clearing this confusion.

These two buttons differing only by icon, are misleading (at least for a beginner).
[image: the misleading two buttons]

What each one represents:

- the left-side button is for pull requests in Azure DevOps Server (TFS) repositories and it belongs to Visual Studio;
- the right-side one is for pull requests in GitHub repositories and belongs to the GitHub Extension;

Comment: [What seems to be a similar case of confusion](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/854944/visual-studio-is-displaying-2-buttons-for-pull-req.html)